# MySQL get row when certain limit has been reached

Tags: mysql

I'm getting an headache of solving the following problem.

We are looking for a query where it retrieves a the data when the SUM(price_total) reached a certain level grouped by type. Table structures are as followed:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Data

```
INSERT INTO `Table1` (`id`, `Date`, `type`, `price_total`)
VALUES
    (1,'2013-02-01 00:00:00',1,5),
    (2,'2013-02-01 00:00:00',2,15),
    (3,'2013-02-02 00:00:00',1,25),
    (4,'2013-02-03 00:00:00',3,5),
    (5,'2013-02-04 00:00:00',4,15),
    (6,'2013-03-05 00:00:00',1,20),
    (7,'2013-08-07 00:00:00',4,15);
```

Example outcome for threshold 15, in chronological order.

```
Type 1: 2013-02-02 00:00:00 Because here it came above 15. (15+5)
Type 2: 2013-02-01 00:00:00
Type 3: n/a SUM(price_total) < 15
Type 4: 2013-02-04 00:00:00
```

To sum up. I want to know the date that they crossed the threshold. Price total should be summed up in chronological order.

Comment: What query do you already have?

Comment: SELECT
 Type,
 SUM(price_total)
FROM
 Table1
GROUP BY Type; Sounds silly... (I'm not a silly MySQL user, but to be honest, I don't know where to start here). Implementing a Having would not work, as we also want Type 3 to appear. Otherwise Type 3 will be filtered out.

Comment: So you are looking for the first moment your sum of values is larger than then a certain threshold.
Let's say you have 3 values for a type, 5,10,12. Does the order of the sum matter? (5+12 > 15, however 10+12 is also larger 15)

Comment: Maybe add a bit larger example on what results you are looking for?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen you are correct. The first moment they reached it in chronological order. I've updated the description.

Comment: I think you can achieve this creating a trigger on insert that calls a function or stored procedure that gets for each row the output you want

Comment: This is not going to be a straightforward SQL. If you need this once, I would just use your preferred programming language. Else I would follow the trigger idea of @GenaroMorales

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple, self explanatory query:

```
select type, min(date) as date
from (
    select t1.type, t1.date, sum(t2.price_total) as total
    from table1 t1
    join table1 t2
      on  t2.type  = t1.type
      and t2.date <= t1.date
    group by t1.type, t1.date
    having total >= 15
) sub
group by type
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/GMAK8269